# How to integrate custom software with Adobe Suite to control and automate it?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-sdk

I want to develop a specialized hardware+software tool that integrates with the Adobe Suite in order to automate it = ease its use for designated use cases. Things such as, but not only:

- Select tool (brush, eraser, copy stamp, ...)
- Increase/decrease tool size, e.g. brush diameter
- Move layer
- Apply filter, ...

Does the Adobe Suite provide an interface to control it? Is the only way to go to write a plugin? Is the Suite controllable/scriptable at all?

Target platforms are:

- MacOS X
- Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Adobe Creative Cloud supports scripting on both Mac and Windows. Specific scripting support varies by products, and includes JavaScript/ExtendScript, AppleScript, and VBScript. Your tags imply that you are interested in Photoshop, which supports all of the above.

Refer to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scripting.html.